# ArrayPad with vectors

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to pad a nested list like

```
M = {{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}}
```

[image]

with some constant "vector", e.g. `{0, 0}`. In that case the desired result would be

```
{{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {a, b}, {c, d}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {e, f}, {g, h}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0,0}}}
```

[image]

However, I somehow can't figure out how to get `ArrayPad` to do what I want directly. My workaround

```
(ArrayPad[M, {{1}, {1}}, foo]) /. foo -> {0, 0}
```

is not pretty and I want to get rid of it. Surely, this can be done with `ArrayPad` alone!

Comment: `ArrayPad[m, {{1, 1}, {1, 1}}, {{{0, 0}}}]`

Comment: or `ArrayPad[m, {{1}, {1}}, {{{0, 0}}}]` if every keystroke counts...Also, I neglected to note in first comment - avoid using uppercase initials for your symbols like the plague - you risk clashing with built-ins...

Comment: Treating your input as a rank-3 tensor: `ArrayPad[{{{a, b}, {c, d}}, {{e, f}, {g, h}}}, {1, 1, 0}, 0]` Replace the third argument with any constant you want.

Comment: Thank you all! Sorry for the trivial question, but I just couldn't figure it out...